# How to get a request parameters like a associative array

Tags: html, associative-array, parameters

Let say I have a list of text fields. Every text field is responsible for some product id, and I want to know how much items should I buy.

The result parameters should be like `{ :1 => 2, :5 => 8 }`, which means that user will buy 2 items of product id 1, and 8 items of product with id 5.

What's the expected `name` attributes of expected `input[type="text"]` html tags for this case?

Comment: Could you provide some details on the platform and language you are working with on the server side? What is parsing the request?

Comment: I'm Rails dev. But I'm interested in raw html now.

Answer (score 0):

Let's you have

```
<input type="text" name="product<?php echo $product_id; >"></input>
```

you can submit the value using jquery like

```
var x = $('input[name=\'product' + pid + '\']').val(); // where pid is any product_id
```

on server you can use

```
$this->request->get['product'.$pid];//pid is any product_id
```

Comment: How can I get an associative array using your answer?